# how to get firebase document as a angular object model

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I save firebase user profile data document id as user id, now I want to get currently logged user data from firebase user collection using currently logged user id and convert it to angular model object I tried some methods but those methods give me errors.

first I get my currently logged user id using below code

```
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
    this.selectedid = user.uid;
```

after I create User object and finally assign it to firebase document data as below

```
getnannies() {
    return this.db.collection('nanny').doc(this.selectedid).valueChanges() 
    as Nanny;
}
```

(Nanny is type of my model class)
then I try to access that document data as below

```
nanny:Nanny;
this.nanny = this.serviceClass.getnannies();
console.log(this.nanny.name);
```

but this method give me errors and I want to know how to do this. my full code attached below

this is my service file

```
export class GetNannyDetailsService {
selectedid: string;
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
private router: Router) {
}

  parseNanny() {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.selectedid = user.uid;}});
  }
getnannies() {
    return this.db.collection('nanny').doc(this.selectedid).valueChanges() 
as Nanny;
}
```

this is my profile.component.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
pronan:Nanny;
constructor(private profile: GetNannyDetailsService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.profile.parseNanny();
    this.pronan = this.profile.getnannies();
    console.log(this.pronan.name);}
```

this is my nanny model

```
export interface Nanny {
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
  nannyId?: string;
  name?: string;
  address?: string;
  number?: string;
  gender ?: string;
  town?: string;
  jobType ?: string;
  birthdate?: Date;
  hourlyRate?: number;
  availability?: string;
  bio?: string;
  imgurl?: string;
}
```

and finally console display "undefined" please help me.

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Answer (score 0):

In service file use one function.

```
getNanny() {
        let s: Subject<Nany> = new Subject();
            this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
              if (user) {

                  this.db.collection('nanny').doc(user.id).get().subscribe(
                      next => {
                      s.next(next.data())
                      });
               }
            });
            return return s as Observable<Nany>
        }
```

In component file, get object by subscribing service method.

```
pronan:Nanny;
constructor(private profile: GetNannyDetailsService) {
}
ngOnInit() {

    this.profile.getnannies().subscribe(nany=>{
    this.pronan=nany
    consple.log(nany)
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ultimatex but that way does not work for me finally I fond working method here it is https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/